# Is it wrong to use php debug_backtrace to get argument from caller function?

Tags: php, debugging

Is it ok to use this code to get some arguments from the calling (as in parent) function?

I do this because i can not easily modify the existing code base (Magento) without fear breaking things.

```
function my_func() {
    // to get first attribute of caller function
    $caller = debug_backtrace();
    $optionValue = current($caller[1][’args’]);
)
function caller($has, $some, $arguments) {
    // ..
    my_func();
    // ..
}
```

Comment: Is it OK to use *for what*? It sure is OK to use if you want to log debugging information.

Comment: Use what for? For anything but *debugging*, I'd say it's *bad*.

Comment: No, it's usually not. [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is usually  better solution.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible but very bad practice. Reasons against:

- a reader can not easily follow program flow (this is called "[spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)")
- it is overhead, compared to just passing the argument
- when some programmer decides the function in question would be very handy to use in another place, strange things may happen.
- when some programmer starts refactoring your code and changes the order of arguments from the caller function, the function in question (where you use this "clever trick") will misteriously fail.

What you clearly should do is just pass the argument to the sub function:

```
function outer ($a, $b, $c) {
    inner($a, $b);
}
function inner($foo, $bar) {   // instead of backtrace magic
    echo $foo+$bar;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. In this situation it's ok to use. To show "task done" for customer in time. And it's Magento Core code. So just passing the argument isn't possible. Code is commented. In future I will change it with Magento configs and several more classes. But this code is so pretty simple :) It's so tempting to use it. But I got your point. You are right. I love StackOverlow. I am newbie here. in contrast to the Magento Forum this one so alive :)

Comment: @user1286094: [- Is the dark side stronger? - No, no, no. Quicker, easier, more seductive.](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0000015/quotes) I know how you feel, and no matter what we say here a day may come for each of us that we are forced to do this due to practical concerns. The idea is that you should feel so dirty about it that you will only do it when you are *desperate*.

Comment: @Jon your comment made me smile.